# Glassfish 2 application on Glassfish 4: "Cannot resolve reference... because there are 2 ejbs in the application"?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, ant, glassfish

So, for the past 2 weeks I've been struggling to fix this issue. My task is to upgrade the application server from glassfish 2 to glassfish 4, and the application which works on GF2 throws this error on my face: "Cannot resolve reference ... because there are [2] ejbs in the application with the interface.."

The application is packaged in an ear which has two war modules inside it. The thing is that both of these modules have the same ejb project as a library added in the libraries when developing on NetBeans. This means that both of these wars do have the same ejb.jar in their WEB-INF/lib folder. I just cant find the way around this. I've tried to remove the ejb from library of both of these projects and just add the ejb-jar in the root of ear, and then define the class-path inside the manifests of these war projects. This resulted in numerous errors on the NetBeans side, and also causing building of these projects fail.

I'm using command line ant to build the wars and place them in an ear.

The thing is that the source code of the projects are NOT done by me, and I'm not sure where i should look into to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you are going to the right direction. Put your ejb-jar file in the lib folder of your .ear file. However there are "changes of rules" in the EE7 regarding placing for instance for root of the persistence. Maybe if you have a persistence.xml file in your ejb-jar it produces the error you see when you put it in the root of the .ear archive

> In the Java Persistence API 1.0, JAR files could be located at the root of an EAR file as the root of the persistence unit. This is no longer supported. Portable applications should use the EAR file's library directory as the root of the persistence unit.

you can find a whole text [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/persistence-intro003.htm)

You would probably want to explore the differences between ee5 and ee7 and especially GF2.x and gf4.x. You may find these links useful [ee7 highlights](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/overview001.htm#GIQVH) and [ee6 highlights](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giqvh.html)